# Failed to check if range is nothing

Tags: vba

**Excel 2007**

I'm stuck.

```
Private Sub check_status_correctness(a_row)

    Dim status_col_rng As Range
    Dim status_val As String
    Dim found_status As Range

    Set status_col_rng = Sheets("Settings").Columns(2)
    status_val = Sheets(MAIN_SHEET).Cells(a_row, STATUS_COL)
    Set found_status = status_col_rng.Find(status_val, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If found_status Is Nothing Then
        Call announce_error(a_row, STATUS_COL)
    End If
End Sub
```

found_status is Nothing at the breakpoing. If I scrutinize found_status in the debugger, it seems to be Nothing. But at the very moment found_status is Nothing gives me False.

Could you help me understand how to catch Nothing?

[image]

Comment: The code you are using is correct, but according to your hardcopy, `found_status` is *not* nothing?

Comment: FunThomas, thank you. You helped me a lot. If you organize this as an answer, I'd gladly accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check for `Nothing` is correct. As the image shows, the object variable `found_status` is *not* nothing (or with other words, was assigned to a Range)

```
Dim r As Range  ' r is not assigned, that means it is nothing
If r Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "r is Nothing"
End If
```

To check if a object variable is assigned:

```
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
If Not r Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "r is assigned"
End If
```